# Multiple messages before effective request

Tags: networking, tcp, communication, consensus

In the context of the 2-generals problem and TCP as a whole, i've been wondering if, in the following situation, there will be any advantage in performing the following communication steps.

Consider the situation where an ATM communicates with its bank to deduct 50$ from a customers account, the situation would go like this:

Situation 1:

ATM     --      Bank

Deduct 50$  ->

<-  Deducted 50$

The ATM would then release the money

Situation 2:

ATM         --           Bank

I want to deduct 50$ ->

<- Ok, if you wish, you can ask me to deduct 50$

Deduct 50$  ->

<-  Deducted 50$

The ATM would then release the money

Is there any advantage in the following situation? Can it be proven that the first communication step is totally unnecessary? Or is there some, maybe out of the box, advantage in the second situation?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As you probably know, the Two Generals Problem is unsolvable. There is always a way to drop messages in such a way that disagreement arises.

In your example the first step is unnecessary because it never impacts the conclusion that any party will draw from the exchange about the transaction. This is not a formal proof and I don't know how to produce one.

That said, in a real banking system the ATM would record what it did and later it would synchronize with the server in case the communication failed mid-way. A double-withdrawal is possible (and this has happened in the real world - bank developers know that they cannot avoid this problem) but the account balance will be fixed up later.